# When did Pickle become part of the Python Standard Library?

Tags: python, pickle

I haven't used Python in almost ten years. And, if I recall correctly, one used to have to pip install pickle; it wasn't part of the Python Standard Library.

[But it seems to be now.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

If I'm correct--when did Pickle become part of the standard Python Library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pickle` is old enough that it was present in [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node31.html), the oldest version for which python.org still has documentation. That was all the way back in 1996. It's way older than pip.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you!